# Работа в командной строке OS X

Tags: linux, macos, shell, консоль

Хочу научиться работать в командной строке OS X. Нашел книгу [Блум, Бреснахэн - Командная Строка Linux](http://www.dialektika.com/books/978-5-8459-1780-5.html).

Вопрос: работа в командных строках Linux и OS X одинакова? Мне подойдет эта книга?

Comment: Нет, работа не одинакова. Хотя похожа.

Comment: Вполне конкретный вопрос на мой взгляд.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, подойдет. Командная строка OS X POSIX-совместима, т.е. команды те же и работают так же. В спорной ситуации вы можете себя проверить, прочитав встроенную документацию, вызываемую командой `man имя_команды`, например `man ls`.

Другое дело что ОС устроена по-другому и в этом данные из книги далеко не всегда будут верны.

В качестве входной точки вы можете использовать курс [Learn the Command Line](https://www.codecademy.com/en/courses/learn-the-command-line) на Codecademy.

Начать рекомендую с установки пакетного менеджера и удобной среды:

1. [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/)

   ```
   ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
   ```
2. [Z shell](http://www.zsh.org/)

   ```
   brew install zsh
   ```
3. [Oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh)

   ```
   sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)"
   ```
4. [iTerm2](https://www.iterm2.com/)

   ```
   brew cask install iterm2
   ```

Новые вопросы по командной строке задавайте с метками [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) и [zsh](/questions/tagged/zsh).